# How to play a short sound on button click using soundPool?

Tags: android, button, soundpool

i have 5 buttons. i want to play short sound every time a button is clicked. Each button will play a different sound from my raw folder. Currently, i can play a sound from the 1st button but how do i assign a sound from another button without creating large amount of codes? pls. help.

here's my code so far:

```
public class Alphabet extends Activity {
private Button a, b, c, d, e;
    private SoundPool spool;
    private int soundID;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabet);

    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
    Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d);
    Button e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e);



    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
          public void onClick(View v) { 
          Sound(); 
          } 
     });

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
          public void onClick(View v) { 
          Sound(); 
          } 
     });

    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
          public void onClick(View v) { 
          Sound(); 
          } 
     });

    d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
          public void onClick(View v) { 
          Sound(); 
          } 
     });

    e.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    { 
          public void onClick(View v) { 
          Sound(); 
          } 
     });

    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.a, 1);


}
public void Sound(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    android.util.Log.v("SOUND","["+volume+"]["+spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f)+"]");
};
```

}

Answer (score -1):

For example You could set parameters into Your Sound() Method like

```
    Sound(int soundID){

      spool.load(this, soundID)
      AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
      float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
```

and put your sound from raw folder inside your onClick into the method:

```
    public void onClick(View v) { 
      Sound(R.raw.a,1); //put the sounds as parameter
      }
```

Comment: eh....yes, but I guess You not. This solution is a short solution without writing much code. That´s what he wanted....